# Display Count of DB Records in PHP Dashboard

Tags: php, sql, database, count, echo

I need to display a "count" of records (rows) in my SQLtable "doctors". This count must appear on my dashboard page in the below  element for total number of doctors

This is index.php for my dashboard page

```
    <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hospital_db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  $content = '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
             <h3><?php echo '.$rows.';?></h3>

              <p>Doctors</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="http://localhost/medibed/doctor" class="small-box-footer">View Doctors <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->

      </div>';
  include('../master.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use mysqli object in new php version try the following code

Make connection first like

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "There are " . $rows . " rows in my table.";

  $content = '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
              *<h3><?php echo "$rows"; } ?></h3>*

              <p>Doctors</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="http://localhost/medibed/doctor" class="small-box-footer">View Doctors <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->

      </div>';
  include('../master.php');
?>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\medibed\Dashboard\index.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\medibed\Dashboard\index.php on line 4
There are rows in my table.

Comment: Did you made coneection ?  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

Comment: You should make connect with your db and use that in query like 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors");

Comment: I added the connection now, and still get:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\medibed\Dashboard\index.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\medibed\Dashboard\index.php on line 5
There are rows in my table.

Comment: if you just need the count then why don't you use the aggregate function count(*) in your query. this much better helps you.

Comment: it is now working thank you - it is just not displaying in the h3 element?
I will edit my code above with what I have now

Comment: is this perhaps incorrect? <h3><?php echo "$rows"; } ?></h3>

Comment: Yes use like <h3><?php echo '.$rows.';</h3> @ultramel1987

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign - nothing is displaying in my <h3> tag.  I edited my code above to show what i have now

Answer (score 0):

if you just need the count then why don't you use the aggregate function count(*) in your query. this much better helps you. and in your code in h3 tag you can concat the string directly rather than using again php code. this might looks better and in structured form.

try this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) as total_rows FROM doctors");
$rows = $result->total_rows;
echo "There are " . $rows . " rows in my table.";
  $content = '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
          *<h3>'.$rows.'</h3>*
          <p>Doctors</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="http://localhost/medibed/doctor" class="small-box-footer">View Doctors <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
  </div>';
include('../master.php');
?>
```